# Symfony's stylesheet not loading

Tags: css, symfony1

I am trying out askeet tutorial for using symfony 1.1.9.

So far it has been fine except for the sytlesheet is not loading, please have a look at the attached image.

The page should look something like [this](http://gnhroofing.ca/getmeapro.ca/web/web/customer_dev.php). Maybe this is a simple tweak and I will appreciate any hint in the right direction.

[image]

Comment: Please use Symfony2, please!

Comment: Hi @erenon, I needed to use this version for some reason. I know symfony2 is much better. Thanks for the advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First**, if you have to choose symfony, right now, for a new development, you should better consider using the [version 2](http://symfony.com/get_started) which is the last one and the most up to date.

---

My guess is that your forgot to define the `/sf` alias inside your Apache configuration.

Your vhost must look like this one:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.7:80>
  DocumentRoot "/home/sfprojects/jobeet/web"
  DirectoryIndex index.php
  <Directory "/home/sfprojects/jobeet/web">
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from All
  </Directory>

  Alias /sf /home/sfprojects/jobeet/lib/vendor/symfony/data/web/sf
  <Directory "/home/sfprojects/jobeet/lib/vendor/symfony/data/web/sf">
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from All
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

*([I took it from the documentation](http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/jobeet/1_4/en/01?orm=Propel#chapter_01_web_server_configuration_the_secure_way))*

See the `/sf` alias? It goes directly to the asset folder of symfony wich will display default image, js and css for common page (the one you tried to load), toolbar, 404, etc ..

Comment: Thanks I managed to solve this problem by creating a softlink to usr/share/php/data/symfony/web/sf in the askeet/web folder. Can't thank you enough. I have to use this version of Symfony for some reason. Thanks alot!